# applying gradient CSS on top of background-color

Tags: css, gradient, opacity

I want to have a solid background color and have a gradient on top of it with a certain opacity. This way it seems one background color with the effect of a gradient on top of it.

This is my html:

```
<article>
    <a href="" class="article">
      <h2>Title<i></i></h2>
      <img src="images/media-examples/pic1.jpg">
    </a>
</article>
```

I want to apply this to the header to create something like this:

[image]

Comment: http://gradients.glrzad.com/ Just make your gradient.. attach the css to the block element on top?

Comment: @SimonPertersen he doesn't need a grad - its a solid block. Needs opacity

Comment: If he just show it wrong he might need one this is the way?? :)

Comment: The solid block already has a lower opacity applied to it, but the gradient should be on top of the block to give the good effect as in the PSD. Is there a way to do this without adding an html tag element and placing it above? If not it seems without an extra element it wont be possible. Thank you for all the answers!

Comment: Sorry for being rude, but in the JPG provided there is no gradient at all, please clarify what you want and we can best help you. A gradient is a difference in color. An opacity is what you have in that JPG.

Comment: @tim.baker maybe i did not explain myself... the JPG provided is the final visual example. The solid backgound has an low opacity applied but there is also a gradient applied on top of this background color. I'm investigating and it seems ::before status is going to be my solution. If I find it I will post it.

Answer (score 5):

Judging by the example, you don't want a gradient. You simply want a overlying element with Opacity. So

HTML

```
<div id="element">
 <div id="overlay">
 <h2>H2 Title</h2>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#element {background:url('image.jpg');}
#overlay {background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);}
```

I won't go in to much more detail as it seams you are wanting a tutorial and really you need to try it, then ask for help when it goes wrong. Try searching the internet, there will be plenty of tutorials on the net.

**Update**
To use your existing HTML try applying this CSS

```
article {width:300px;}
article img {position:fixed; top:0; border:3px solid #253d8e; z-index:99;}
article h2 {z-index:999; position:fixed; top:0; color:#fff; background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); width:290px; display:inline-block;margin:0; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-left:10px;}
```

You will need to update this to suit your needs but should give you an idea. See it working [here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8nhGA/)

Comment: I already searched and couldnt find what i needed. I wanted to not change the html5 structure at all. I thought before and after would help but it does not seem to... thank you for your tip anyway

Answer (score 0):

I would add another element over the image that has a background with opacity ... this way you can easily control all attributes.

You could also apply two backgrounds to the same element or use pseudo elements
like here: http://nicolasgallagher.com/multiple-backgrounds-and-borders-with-css2/

Edit: Sorry, Tim was just a tiny bit faster with the same but more detailed overlay element answer =)
But now I just want some credit for the other two suggestions ;-)

Comment: I already checked this website you are talking about. I tried to apply the gradient to :before. This way the gradient would be on top of the element physically but it did not work. What am I doing wrong?